# Automata and power series

Tags: reference-request, power-series, automata

I am taking a class on Automata and Formal Languages and I need to solve an exercise, but I have no idea where to start from. It sounds like this:

> Decide the coefficients of the words in $\{a,b\}^*$, which in the following 
>       formal power series occur (the semirings are already known):
>
> $(a+b)^{n}, (a+b)^*$ (for the boolean semiring and for the semiring of the nonnegative integers plus infinity)

Can you help me please? And could you indicate me some literature in which I could read something about formal power series?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This formulation seems strange to me.

Comment: I don't know what to say... for me is everything new and unknown.

Comment: Neither do I. I've worked with all the concepts mentioned in your post, but I'm still unsure what the question is about...

Comment: @dtldarek I found out that I have to decide the coefficients of the power series. For example, (a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = aa + ab + ba + bb for both boolean semiring and semiring of nonnegative integers plus infinity.

Answer (score 0):

As to literature:

G. Lallement, *Semigroups and combinatorial applications*, John Wiley & Sons Inc (1979), Chapter 9.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.